# Open source Magic Eye generator

Tags: linux, image, open-source

Do you remember those Magic Eye images that contain a 3D object? I love them!
Are there any open source programs for generating Magic Eye pictures, which ideally work on Linux.

I found a [Gimp plugin](http://sites.inka.de/bunsen/alex/english/gimp/magic.99.html), but haven't managed to get it working yet.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a package in Ubuntu for a program called **Stereograph**. It's website is here:

http://stereograph.sourceforge.net/index.html

Here's a tutorial on how to make them using GIMP, Blender and Stereograph:

http://linuxgazette.net/104/kapil.html

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty basic, but you should try openstereogram, it's OS independent:

http://code.google.com/p/openstereogram/

Answer (score 1):

There's also this JavaScript app:

http://guciek.github.com/imagzag.html (use the "Magic Eye" option)